# python list variables dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

Below I am trying to read a file and store every other second and third lines.
I have 4000 lines but there is a pattern of 4 lines which repeats 1000 times.
After I have read and split the lines into three variables `x,y,z`. But these are string variables. Next for-loop I am trying to convert the lists into numpy arrays. I use a dictionary for this. However, at the end of the code when I print the type of `y` is still a `str` variable. As I understand from what happens python did not store the numpy array `p` as `y`, although I loop over `x,y,z`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fl = open('input.sis','r')

lines = []
x = []
y = []
z = []
for i in range(1000):
   line = []
   for j in range(4):
      f= fl.readline()
      line.append(f)
   lines.append(line)

   xyz = lines[i][2].split(' ')
   x.append(xyz[0])
   y.append(xyz[1])
   z.append(xyz[2])
fl.close()

dic = {'x':x,'y':y,'z':z}
for k in dic:
    p = dic[k]
    p = np.asfarray(p)
    print(type(p))
print(type(y[0]))
```

Any idea how to tell python to recognize that `p = np.asfarray(p)` is actually y = np.asfarray(y) and when I print the type of `y` at the end to be `float` instead of `str`? Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Here is the output of the code:
`<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'str'>`

Answer (score 0):

A way to understand what happens is to replace `=` by `is now a name for`.

What you do in your loop is:

- `p` is now a name for `dic[k]`
- `p` is now a name for the output of `np.asfarray(p)`

and so on, in each loop. When you leave the `for` loop, `p` refers to the output of `np.asfarray(dic('z'))`. And that's all that happened here.

If you want to update the values in your dict, you should do:

```
dic = {'x':x,'y':y,'z':z}
for k in dic:
    dic[k] = np.asfarray(dic[k])
```

or, a bit nicer:

```
for key, value in dic.items():
    dic[key] = np.asfarray(value)
```

Now, `dic['y'] refers to the array returned by`np.asfarray`

But you haven't done anything to `y`, so it still refers to the same object as before. If you want to change that, you must write something like `y = ....`

You could for example do:

```
y = dic['y']
```

For a more thorough explanation, have a look at [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: I wasn't able to understand the interim dictionary the OP is using. Can't it be dropped and just use something like `vstack`?

Comment: @ Thierry Lathuille 
The whole idea why I am using a dictionary is because I will have many variables and I don't want to write e.g. `y = np.asfarray(y)`. `y` is a list of strings, I get that. But in the for-loop I am trying to loop over the variable names `x,y,z` to convert them to numpy arrays. How do you loop over variable names?

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in dic:
    p = dic[k]
    p = np.asfarray(p)
    print(type(p))
```

Should be

```
for k in dic:
    p = dic[k]
    dic[k] = np.asfarray(p)
    print(type(p))
```

When you set `p = dic[k]` you are calling `dic[k]` and retrieving a value, now, since `dic[`x`] == x` now `p == x`. Now when you are trying to assign that value to its corresponding key you want to call `dic[k] = np.asfarry(p)` this translates to `dic['x'] = np.asfarry(x)` and now it is assigned to the value for the corresponding key.

Here's a visual to break it down whats happening

```
dicta = {'a': 1 }

for k in dicta:
    print(dicta[k])
    p = dicta[k]
    print(p)
    dicta[k] = 3*p

print(dicta[a])
```

> ```
> 1
> 1
> 3
> ```

Comment: @vash_the_stamede I think I found a solution which does what I want:

`dic = {'x':x,'y':y,'z':z}
for k in sorted(dic):
    print(k)
    globals()[k] = np.asfarray(dic[k])`

in that way the operations in the for-loop are applied to the `y` variable directly.

Comment: @user3578925 happy to hear that just offering ideas!

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in range(1000):
       line = []
       for j in range(4):
          f= fl.readline()
          line.append(f)
       lines.append(line)

       xyz = lines[i][2].split(' ')
       x.append(xyz[0])
       y.append(xyz[1])
       z.append(xyz[2])
    fl.close()

    dic = {'x':x,'y':y,'z':z}
    for k in dic:
        p = dic[k]
        p = np.asfarray(p)
        print(type(p))
    print(type(y[0]))
```

The answer to the question I asked is to use `globals()`. Some people would discourage you using it but is the only solution I could find. Let me explain:
Right in the first for-loop `y.append(xyz[1])` will return `y` as list of `<str>`, where the same holds for `x` and `z`.
Step 2. I create a dictionary of these variables `x`,`y` and `z` and their values.
Step 3. I want to loop over each variable in `dic` and change the type of `x`, `y`,`z` from `str` list to numpy arrays.
Therefore when I print the type of `y[0]` it is still `str`.
Now if the second loop is replaced by:

```
dic = {'x':x,'y':y,'z':z}
for k in sorted(dic):
    globals()[k] = np.asfarray(dic[k])
print(type(y[0]))
```

I get for `type(y[0])`:
`<type 'numpy.float64'>`